# How to get 29 Feb using AddYears method in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, leap-year

We use a job which runs every day and perform some action for a day one year ahead.
Actually we just use something like: `DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1)`.
But it seems not possible to get a 29 February(e.g for 2020) using this technique:

```
var target = new DateTime(2020, 2, 29);
bool result = (target == target.AddYears(-1).AddYears(1));//false
```

So is it possible to target a 29 February in future somehow?

Comment: Are you trying to e.g. target "the last day of the month of February"? If so, you'll probably be looking at some manual construction based on `DaysInMonth` but you're not really made your *requirement* clear in the question...

Comment: Maybe use IsLeapYear (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.isleapyear?view=netframework-4.7.2)  
If resulting date is 1st march -> IsLeapYear == true -> Fix date by subtracting a day.
I am not sure about your code example since it actually does opposite from operation in your description.

Comment: It is not totally clear what you are asking for - if you are performing an action for a date exactly one year ahead then as you do not have a Feb 29th in the year preceding a leap year then you wouldn't expect to have anything scheduled for that day. You would need to decide on when to perform actions 1 year on from 29th in leap year - should it be a day early or late?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addyears?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_AddYears_System_Int32_) states:

> - If value + DateTime.Year is also a leap year, the return value represents the leap day in that year. For example, if four years is added to February 29, 2012, the date returned is February 29, 2016.
> - If value + DateTime.Year is not a leap year, the return value represents the day before the leap day in that year. For example, if one year is added to February 29, 2012, the date returned is February 28, 2013.

This means if you add a year you will always get Feb 28th. The only way to get 29th via `AddYears` is if you add a multiple of 4.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is by [design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addyears?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> If the current instance represents the leap day in a leap year, the
>   return value **depends on the target date**:
>
> - If `value` + `DateTime.Year` is also a leap year, the return value
>     represents the leap day in that year. For example, if four years is
>     added to February 29, 2012, the date returned is February 29, 2016.
> - If `value` + `DateTime.Year` is not a leap year, the return value
>     represents **the day before the leap day** in that year. For example, if
>     one year is added to February 29, 2012, the date returned is February
>     28, 2013.

1 year after 29th Feb 2020 *should be* 28th Feb 2021 since it is *not* a leap year. But in such a case, all the years after 2021 will work as a 28th February.

Other than this, ask yourself, what is the meaning of a "year" for you? How many days in a month? How many days in a year? Is it 365? 366? Or as [wikipedia stated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year) 365.2425? Also, which calendar we are talking about?

Frameworks, libraries etc.. does *not* work like people think. They work based on a set of rules that defined before. .NET Framework defined this rule as such. So, when you add a year to a `DateTime` instance, what they decide is month part has to stay same, year part will change for how many years will be added, and the day part must be a *valid* one.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. At least for now I'm going to use `.AddDays(365)` instead of `AddYears(1)`.

Comment: Keep in mind if you do that then your backups won't line up - whenever the current year is a leap year and the date is between feb-feb next year, sometimes you'll be backing up say, June 1st on May 31st, and sometimes you'll be backing up June 1st on June 1st, depending on how the offset goes.

Comment: @RomanKoliada `AddDays(365)` is not the same as `AddYears(1)` by the way. But with this, you will guaranteed to work in every 365 days. Look, `TicksPerMillisecond`, `TicksPerMillisecond`, `TicksPerDay` are constants for .NET framework for example. They don't change based on leap year or any other things. But when you start to work with larger units like "month" or "year", these subjects in computing depends on a lot of things. That's why they "have to" defined in some set of rules if you wanna get stable results when you dealing with them.

Comment: @RomanKoliada - `AddDays(365)` is an anti-pattern.  If you use that, then whether you start on Feb 29 or not, if you *cross* Feb 29 then your results will be off by a day.  For example, `2019-10-01` + `365 days` = `2020-09-30` (instead of the expected `2020-10-01`).  See [my blog post](https://codeofmatt.com/happy-new-leap-year/) from last leap year.

Answer (score 0):

You could cheat the system a bit by taking "the day before march 1st" instead.

stub:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.UtcNow
if (today.month == 2)
{
  if(today.day == 28 || today.day == 29)
  {
    today.AddDays(1).AddYears(1).AddDays(-1)
   }
}
```

this converts your feb 28 on non-leapyears in march 1st, adds a year, and goes to the day before that.
If the next year also is not a leapyear, you will still get feb 28, but if next year is a leapyear, the result will be feb 29.

this does not deal yet with the situation that this year is a leapyear, as this code will then return febuary 27th instead though

Answer (score 0):

Function that return the next 29. feb. Maybe it helps.
    using System;

```
public class Program
{
    public static DateTime NextTwentyNineFeb()
    {
        int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        while(true){            
            try{
                var target = new DateTime(year, 2, 29);
                Console.WriteLine(target);
                return target;
            }
            catch
            {
                year++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As NibblyPig stated, this isn't possible. However, if you are actually just looking for the end of the month, then you can use `new DateTime(year, month + 1, 0).AddDays(-1)`

Comment: 0 is an invalid day and `month+1` won't work in December.

Comment: Quite right, I now remember falling into these traps when I was implementing an EndOfMonth() extension method. I think I ended up making use of DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)